# How to edit htaccess for pretty URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have my site as below:

|_index.php
|_index.php?page=about
|_articles {DIR}
  |_articles/index.php?page=2
  |_articles/article_detail.php?id=1
|_events {DIR}
  |_events/event_detail.php?event_id=1

How do I make htaccess to use URLs like

mysite.com/about
mysite.com/articles/page/1/
mysite.com/articles/1/
mysite.com/events/1/

Comment: Welcome to SO! I suggest that you make an attempt, then show us what you tried and what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^articles/([^/]+)/?$ /articles/article_detail.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^articles/page/([^/]+)/?$ /articles/index.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^events/([^/]+)/?$ /events/event_detail.php?id=$1 [L]
```